# why nifty_generators not being recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have installed nifty_generators successfully. Though, when i run the following command:

```
rails generate nifty_authentication
```

i get the error:

```
Could not find generator nifty_authentication.
```

I have included gem 'nifty_generators' in my gem file. What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things after looking [on its github](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators).

First, I believe the gem is call `nifty-generators` not `nifty_generators`, which may be causing you some other problems as well.

Second, per the instructions , you should be calling it via `rails g nifty:authentication`.